# How do I group all the months for each year?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have a DB with a column called "post_date". Each entry is Y-M-D, so like 2013-06-01.

What I want to do is display on my page using PHP like this:

```
2013
06-01, 05-31, 05-30, etc

2012
06-01, 05-31, 05-30, etc

2011
06-01, 05-31, 05-30, etc
```

The month and day is whatever's in the database. I've tried GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) but with no success. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Search for `group_concat` function

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL?

Comment: SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year, MONTH(post_date) AS month, DAY(post_date) AS day FROM archives GROUP BY YEAR(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC

Comment: What's the type of the column `post_date`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year, 
       MONTH(post_date) AS month, 
       DAY(post_date) AS day 
FROM archives 
ORDER BY YEAR(post_date) ASC, 
         MONTH(post_date) ASC, 
         DAY(post_date) ASC
```

**EDIT**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year, 
        MONTH(post_date) AS month, 
        DAY(post_date) AS day 
    FROM archives 
    WHERE YEAR(post_date) = :currentYear 
    ORDER BY YEAR(post_date) ASC, 
        MONTH(post_date) ASC, 
        DAY(post_date) ASC
");

 $startYear = 2003;
 $endYear = 2013;

 for($y = $startYear; $y<=$endYear; $y++)
 {
     echo $y . '<br />';

     $stmt->bindValue(':currentYear', $y);
     $stmt->execute();

     foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
     {
         echo $row['month'] . '-' . $row['day'] . '; ';
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you want it formatted in the way in your original post, its not possible with pure SQL. You would need to use PHP to loop through the years you want to retrieve, and use a prepared query to retrieve recordsets where the `(db) year` is the same as the current loops year. I'll update my answer

Comment: Exactly. I know it's not just SQL, that's why the PHP side is a bit confusing. The SQL I think I have it.

Comment: @Ironank, I have updated my answer to include the PHP needed.

Comment: You'll obviously have to hook it up to your database, I've used a pdo query as it's what I normally use

Answer (score 0):

So far I have:

`SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year, MONTH(post_date) AS month, DAY(post_date) AS day 
FROM archives 
GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR(post_date) DESC, MONTH(post_date) DESC, DAY(post_date) DESC`

But the 2 last rows are not showing.

The format I get is:
2013
0601

2013
0531

So I'm confused as to how I can loop through without the year inside the loop, but being looped.

Answer (score 0):

select all needed rows and then in php use loop:

```
foreach($sqlArray as $result){
    $date = explode(' ',$result['post_date']);
    $Ymd = explode('-',$date);
    $resultArray[$Ymd[0]][] = $Ymd[1].'-'.$Ymd[2];
}
foreach($resultArray as &$array){
    arsort($array);
}
```

or try `array_map($resultArray,'arsort');` and then

```
foreach($resultArray as $year=>$dates){
echo $year;
    foreach($date as $date){
echo $date;
     }
}
```